# Playing video by embed tag in Windows XP

Tags: html, video, windows-xp, embed

While playing video by embed tag in `src`, mp4 and swf file are working but playing flv is not working in any browser on my Windows XP system. How can I fix it?

```
<embed src="videoplayback.flv" bgcolor="#000"
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"

name="mainflash1"  autostart="false" loop="false" height="450" width="450" allowscriptaccess="samedomain"
 >
<noembed>Sorry, your browser doesn't support the embedding of multimedia.</noembed>
</embed>
```

Comment: Ya , anyways i solved it with object tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For playing FLV in html, you should use the `<object>` tag. For example:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
width="320" height="240" 
wmode="transparent" 
data="player.swf?file=video.flv&autoStart=false">
<param name="movie" 
value="player.swf?file=video.flv&autoStart=false"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
</object>
```

Player.swf is player swf file and filename is the file attribute.

Comment: Yes, this is a much better solution. +1 for the magic of self-discovery. :-)